# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Portal Comments based on security roles

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

We want to establish restrictions for certain users based on security roles. For example:

My work space: `Activities -> Portal comments`

[image: Graphical description]

Or to write them directly on the entity's form. For example: `Sales - Leads -> Leads`:

[image: Test]

Since Portal comment is not an entity but an "activity type" I don't know where to update those restrictions for security roles, if there is any. Any suggestions to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately activities cannot be segregated by type in security roles. All activities including custom activity is governed by single entity. That means whatever you give like user level or BU level access, that privilege applies to all activity types (Portal comments, Email, Phonecall, etc).

If you have 2 security roles for 2 different user base, then remove the Read/Edit privilege against Activity entity of those users security role for whom you don’t want to show any activity menu/records.